# How to write a model with a hybrid method that takes query parameters

Tags: sqlalchemy

Here's a simplified use case of what I'm trying to do:

```
class Location(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'locations'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.UnicodeText, nullable=False)

    # a postgres EARTH type
    earth_location = db.deferred(db.Column(EARTH))

    @hybrid_method
    def location_distance_from_current_location(self, current_latitude, current_longitude):
        return db.func.earth_distance(
            db.func.ll_to_earth(
                current_latitude, current_longitude), self.earth_location)
```

I know how to write the SQL for this, but how do I model this in SQLAlchemy?

```
SELECT
    locations.id, locations.name,
    earth_distance(ll_to_earth(40.766810, -73.978227), locations.earth_location) AS location_distance_from_current_location
FROM
    locations
WHERE (earth_box(ll_to_earth(40.766810, -73.978227, 10000) @> locations.earth_location)
ORDER BY location_distance_from_current_location ASC
```

How do I get the `current_latitude` and `current_longitude` values passed in to the hybrid method? I don't need to use the hybrid method as a `filter` because that's taken care of me by the `earth_box()` function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A hybrid method is a method that has both a Python implementation and a SQL implementation. You've provided the SQL implementation but not the Python implementation. Your best recourse here is to provide the Python implementation.

If you don't need to access `location_distance_from_current_location` on each instance, you can fetch the value when you are querying:

```
session.query(Location, Location.location_distance_from_current_location(...)).filter(...)
```

This gives you a list of `(Location, distance)` tuples.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of the hybrid method. Actually maybe a hybrid method is the wrong tool for the job. I don't need a Python implementation. I just need the correct SQL to execute and return the `distance_from_current_location` as a part of the location object.

Comment: @lostdorje The point is that what you want isn't really possible, precisely because it requires the input of latitude and longitude. The best you can do is to query it separate from the `Location` object.